# field set in visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, lightning-design-system

I have created field set and using it in visualforce page, I have included all the fields from field set in viusalforce page using  but there is an issue with the css, css is not working properly my code is,

**Visualforce Page**

```
<div class="slds-form-element__control">
   <apex:repeat value="{!FieldfrmFieldSet}" var="fs">         
        <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="text-input-01">{!fs.label}</label>
        <apex:inputfield styleClass="slds-select" value="{!objContact1[fs]}" required="{!OR(fs.required, fs.dbrequired)}"/>
   </apex:repeat>
</div>
```

**My Controller**

```
public class FieldSetController {

    public Contact objContact1{get;set;} 

    public FieldSetController()
    {
      objContact1 = new Contact();
    }

    public List<Schema.FieldSetMember> getFieldfrmFieldSet()
    {
      return SObjectType.Contact.FieldSets.New_Contact.getFields();
    }
}
```

**Problem in css**
[image]

I'm sharing the screenshot.. the css is not working properly.. If I scroll the page position for lookup icons also changes..

**I'm expecting like this**
[image]

Comment: why don't you use `pageBlockTable`?. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Rohit Mourya still I have to use <apex:repeat> to iterate through fields... again the issue is same with css.. is their any way include fields in vf page directly instead of <apex:repeat> ..

Answer (score 1):

Directaly use FieldSet into Vf page:

Vf Page:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.ObjectName.FieldSets.FieldSetName}"  var="field">
        <apex:inputField value="{!ObjectRecord[field.fieldPath]}"
                         required="{!OR(field.required, field.dbrequired)}" />
</apex:repeat>
```

In Controller assign memory for object:

```
Public class Controller {
    public Object ObjectRecord {get; set;}
    // Constructor
    public Controller(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
       ObjectRecord = new object();
    }
}
```